# Angular 2 dropdown list not loading since the http response is slow

Tags: angular, html-select, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I was trying to load dropdown list from http response using angular2 service.

Here is my service method :

```
categories: any;
    getCategories() {
        let subscription = this.httpclient
          .get(this.server_url)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.categories = data;
            console.log(this.categories);
          });
      }
```

Component TS

```
categoryID: number;
constructor(public categoryservice: CategoryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryservice.getCategories();
  }
```

And component html code is :

```
<select data-width="20%" class="selectpicker" [(ngModel)]="categoryID">
       <option *ngFor="let category of categoryservice.categories" value= {{category.categoryId}} >{{category.categoryName}}</option>
 </select>
```

But since the response in getCategories() method takes a while, dropdown list is empty. If the response comes fast list loads properly.

Can anyone please help me in this scenario when response takes time to fetch data from server? How I can load the list after reponse comes?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the select around another `div` or `ng-container` and then check if the data is present or not and then only show the select option .

Like

```
<ng-container *ngIf = "categoryservice?.categories">
<select data-width="20%" class="selectpicker" [(ngModel)]="categoryID">
       <option *ngFor="let category of categoryservice.categories" value= {{category.categoryId}} >{{category.categoryName}}</option>
 </select>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: tried the same. But no luck. 
Though the data receives after 2 seconds, <select> is loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can render your dropdown after the response comes with a simple *ngIf on your select, while before you can render a loading:

```
<my-loading *ngIf="!loadComplete"></my-loading>

<select *ngIf="loadComplete" data-width="20%" class="selectpicker" [(ngModel)]="categoryID">
       <option *ngFor="let category of categoryservice.categories" value= {{category.categoryId}} >{{category.categoryName}}</option>
</select>
```

And in your TS you just set `loadComplete` to `true` after your call is complete

```
loadComplete: boolean = false;

getCategories() {
        let subscription = this.httpclient
          .get(this.server_url)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.categories = data;
            this.loadComplete = true;
        }, err => {
           this.loadComplete = true;
           alert("An error occurred");
        });
}
```

Since you can't speed up your call, this way you render a loading until the call is completed. Hope it helps

Comment: this.loadComplete = true  not reflecting though its changing after getting the response, 
and 
*ngIf="categoryservice.loadComplete" still false so <select> is not loading

Comment: Are you using onPush strategy?

Comment: Not using onPush. 
Its a simple rest service call, which returns json data like
"[{ "categoryId": 2, "categoryName": "asd" }, { "categoryId": 3, "categoryName": "qqq" }, { "categoryId": 6, "categoryName": "error" }]"

So I wanted it to load on <select> list
Since the response is taking around 2 seconds , the list is not populating

Comment: Maybe there is an error, try to edit your code as I edited my answer

Comment: There is no error in request response.
No alert is poping up.

Comment: Put a log also in the success function. Something should popup, it is success or error, mandatory